# how to modify svg text/tspan tag edit and reflect on same style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am using D3.js for modify svg i want to modify(edit) svg multiple text without input box reflect on same style. I have browsing the internet but i can't find a proper solution to my problem. I need to change the text in an svg. I am also trying to contenteditable but not working properly. I want smooth editing like to input box, text area. cursor start with end and if back space then remove only current selected element.

```js
d3.select(".main-cointaner").attr("contenteditable", "true")
default_text_drag_drop()
// text options
var ta = 0;

function default_text_drag_drop() {
  document.querySelectorAll("text").forEach(function(e, ta) {
    d3.select(e).classed("text_number" + ta, true)
    var default_text_move_node = [];
    var default_text_move = d3.select(".text_number" + ta).node().outerHTML;
    default_text_move_node.push('<g class="text_number_g' + ta + '">' + default_text_move + '</g>');
    d3.select(".text_number" + ta).node().outerHTML = default_text_move_node;
    
    d3.select(".text_number_g" + ta)
      .attr("cursor", "move")
      .classed("g_logo_moving", true)
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragStart)
        .on('drag', dragging)
        .on('end', dragEnd)
      )
  });
}

function dragStart(d, i, nodes) {
  d3.select(".hightligh_cliked_area").remove()
  d3.select(nodes[i])
}

function dragging(d, i, nodes) {
  this.x = this.x || 0;
  this.y = this.y || 0;
  this.x += d3.event.dx;
  this.y += d3.event.dy;
  
  d3.select(nodes[i])
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")", function(d) {
      return d.x
    }, function(d) {
      return d.y
    });
}

function dragEnd(d, i, nodes) {
  d3.select(nodes[i])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-cointaner">
  <div class="svg-div">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1080 1080" width="1421.9100341796875">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1{fill:none;}
          .cls-2{fill:#b3c497;}
          .cls-3{fill:#fff;}
          .cls-4,.cls-9{fill:#00080d;}
          .cls-5{opacity:0.5;}
          .cls-6{clip-path:url(#clip-path);}
          .cls-7{fill:#ddcfdf;}
          .cls-10,.cls-8,.cls-9{isolation:isolate;}
          .cls-9{font-size:83.73px;}
          .cls-10,.cls-9{font-family:Helvetica;}
          .cls-10{font-size:55.42px;fill:#7d8890;}
          .cls-11{letter-spacing:-0.02em;}
        </style>
        
        <clipPath id="clip-path">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M438.64,655.29l0,0c145.28-101.08,181.11-300.8,80-446.08L372.7,0H0V587.77C112.94,718.48,305.07,748.16,438.64,655.29Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      
      <g id="Layer_4" data-name="Layer 4">
        <g id="Layer_3-2" data-name="Layer 3">
          <g id="text2" class="cls-8"><g class="" cursor="" style="">
            <text class="cls-9 text_number0" transform="translate(649.01 251.37)">
              <tspan class="svgtextforhiddne" text-anchor="middle" x="188.43748474121094">Idli makes</tspan>
              <tspan x="182.83543395996094" y="100.48" class="svgtextforhiddne" text-anchor="middle">it the best</tspan>
              <tspan x="183.8249969482422" y="200.95" class="svgtextforhiddne" text-anchor="middle">breakfast.</tspan>
            </text>
          </g>
        </g>
        
        <circle id="ele1" class="cls-4" cx="847.79" cy="874.44" r="162.22"></circle>

        <g id="text1">
          <g class="cls-8">
            <g class="text_number_g1 g_logo_moving" cursor="move" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
              <text class="cls-10 text_number1" transform="translate(754.54 829.64)">
                <tspan class="svgtextforhiddne" text-anchor="middle" x="95.83470153808594">20% off</tspan>
              </text>
            </g>
            
            <g class="text_number_g2 g_logo_moving" cursor="move" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
              <text class="cls-10 svgtextforhiddne text_number2" transform="translate(781.79 896.15)" text-anchor="middle" x="66.23999786376953">on all</text>
            </g>
            
            <g class="text_number_g3 g_logo_moving" cursor="move" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
              <text class="cls-10 svgtextforhiddne text_number3" transform="translate(778.71 962.66)" text-anchor="middle" x="69.32249450683594">menu</text>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      
      </g>
      
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Wrapper end-->
```

Comment: Fabric.js might be better suited for this task. It creates an editable canvas context, but you can export the final result as svg. Have a look at the [demos](http://fabricjs.com/super-sub-script)

Comment: Thank you for your usefull answer. I'm trying to work on the context, that's the exact thing i was thinking of. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: i am tried but when i click on tspan and curved text font style and position not working properly.